# authenticating MVC 5 application using Third part other then Social networks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity

I got MVC 5 application Using asp.net identity for authentication works fine.

I want my MVC 5 application to use authentication from an already existing application with Traditional Asp.net authentication

I want Existing Traditional Asp.net authentication application to be used as single Sign-on and mvc application to use auth cookie

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: i dont know how to do it i am new to Identity

Comment: Can you elaborate on the nature of single-sign-on you want.  Is it just reusing the id/password for the user? Or do you want auth session sharing, i.e. a person signing into your ASP.NET site then browsing to the MVC 5 site without logging in again?

Comment: a person signing into your ASP.NET site get authentication cookie then browsing to the MVC 5 site without logging in again using the same cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

You can create your own custom ApplicationUser (IdentityUser) and also create your own UserStore that implements the IUserStore interface.

Just check out the default ApplicationUserManager in the first line of the Create function you will see that ApplicationManager get constructed with a new UserStore. There you can plug in your custom User & UserStore.

Here is some good info.
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Comment: I want Existing Traditional Asp.net authentication application to be used as single Sign-on and mvc application to use auth cookie

Comment: If you  are using ASP.net SimpleMembership Provider then I dont think Single sign on is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use the old FormsAuthentication module in MVC5 application.
http://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/forms-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc/

Just make sure to redirect unauthorized requirest to your original login page.